# Dropdown button is not customizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have added a basic clickable dropdown button to my menu, but it can't be customize or even show the changes on the live website. And the dropdown content will not appear on separate line:

Here is a screenshot of what i am referring too:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9lfn.jpg

I have searched google related to my problem, but everything I've searched is not working. Am I doing something wrong

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.button')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 130px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.nav-menu a img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  margin-top: -130px;
}

.nav-menu li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-menu li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  border-top: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

.nav-menu li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-menu .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.nav-menu li.social {
  float: right;
}

li.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

li.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-menu .button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

li.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown-menu:hover .button,
.button:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-menu-content {
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu-content a {
  float: left;
  color: red;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-menu-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title Here</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css?v=12345">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
      <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.jpg" style="width:50px"></a>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Games</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Crews</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li class="navbar">
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
  </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-content" id="myDropdown">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>

      </li>
      <li class="social">
        <a href="#">Sign In</a>
        <a href="#" style="color:#ff0000">Sign Up</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
      </li>

      </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried writing css with more specificity like

```
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
```

However if what you meant was it gets applied locally and not when deployed on to live site **it could be due to css caching by browser** in which case you can use a cache busting [strategy](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/) like appending a query string(unique) at the end of url when linking the css eg 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./path/to/cssfile.css?v=12345">.`

Comment: ohh :/, if you can provide all the code / html and replication of what you have at the moment would help in providing a better answer. At the moment it seems like its missing some html etc. You can use a sandbox like https://codepen.io/ to provide a working example of as it is at the moment

Comment: try the above with !important to see if there's override on your current class. Ex: *margin: 0 !important;*

Answer (score 0):

i've tried your code & there should be no problem.
I think its because your style was overridden by another class. You can check it with browser inspector.
In that case you should prioritize yous css by using `!important` like this

```
.dropdown-menu-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block !important;
  text-align: left;
}
```

you can find more info about css specificity here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: that worked, but it is not working, when it comes to putting the links on a separate line

Comment: have you check on browser's inspector?

Comment: Yeah i have checked the inspector :/

Comment: from your screenshot, i'm pretty sure it was overridden by another class. btw, just guessing, can you check `.dropdown-menu-content` or `#myDropdown` in the inspector, is it styled with display:flex or something like that? maybe it's the container's style that make the links inline

Comment: out of clues :( providing full code like @Dasith suggestion will help us a lot to provide more accurate answer

Comment: full code is above as i updated when @Dasith suggested it

Comment: i mean the code that has problem in it :) or perhaps you can add screenshots of your live site's web inspector, pointing on elements with problems